# laravel test assertJsonValidationErrors false positive on multiple fields

Tags: laravel, tdd

```
  $data = [
        'name' => '', // required field
        'email' => '' // required field
  ];
  // or $data = [];

  $this->postJson('api/users', $data)
        ->assertStatus(422)
        ->assertJsonValidationErrors(
            ['name']
        );
```

I am writing tests for validating the fields. The above test will pass, which I expect to fail because name and email fields are both required and should be both in the validation errors. How can I force assertJsonValidationErrors to check all fields in the error bag. Thanks.

Comment: What about simply doing this: `$this->...->assertJsonValidationErrors(['name', 'email']);`

Comment: @KevinBui I could, but the point is assertJsonValidationErrors is not checking the exact fields in the errors. Imagine if I add another required field like `gender` later on, I would expect `$this->...->assertJsonValidationErrors(['name', 'email']);` to fail, so I am reminded there is something missing in my code, but it will always pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thinking and digging into laravel documentation, I found a solution to it: use `assertJson` instead of `assertJsonValidationErrors`

```
  $data = [
        'name' => '', // required field
        'email' => '' // required field
  ];
  // or $data = [];

  $this->postJson('api/users', $data)
        ->assertStatus(422)
        ->assertJson(function (AssertableJson $json) use ($data) {
                $json->has('message')
                    ->has('errors', 2) // it will check the exact size of the errors bag
                    ->whereAllType([
                        'errors.name' => 'array',
                        'errors.email' => 'array',
                    ]);
            });
```